# Are there two or more environment files on Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS?

Tags: environment-variables, openjdk

Hi: I am trying to install OpenJDK on my Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 LTS. The problem is I need to modify my $PATH variable to contain the OpenJDK path instead of the oracle java.
java -version gives me java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
when I echo my $PATH I get:**FIRST ENVIRONMENT FILE**
/home/mikeg/bin:/home/mikeg/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
when I do whereis $PATH I get bin: /usr/local/bin which contains just three PIP files
when I do sudo gedit /etc/environment I get:**SECOND ENVIRONMENT FILE**
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java"
so where is the first environment file located?

Comment: The bold text is just for your readability. Thanks.

Comment: There is only a single true environment file, however shell initialization files such as `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` etc. may (and in fact usually do) define and/or modify environment variables.

Comment: So how do I find the file and edit it with the openjdk information?

Comment: Checked the files you mentioned but no path entries found. Is there a chain of files being read on start up?

Comment: I found a solution to update java to open java from an earlier question:  sudo update-alternatives --config java
this is quick and easy but I would still like to know which file has the Path and where it is.